# Scheduling multiple repeating alarms

Tags: java, android, repeatingalarm

Sorry for my bad english.
Currently I'am working at the project with qr code scanner.I'am facing this bug. When app scan the qr code it should schedule the repetition of alarms. It works very well but if I gave the alarm manager for example 3 alarms.For example now is  12:00 and first is at 11:00,second at 12:30 and third at 13:00.None of them trigger. So this is my test code.
Repetition and counter are global variable starting at 0.
There is also no error and I try to test it with printing every result and I really don't see the logic error.Please help,thank you.
So it is working if i don't put this part of code.

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() > cal.getTimeInMillis()){
                        TimeUntilTrigger = cal.getTimeInMillis() + 86400000;

                    }else{
                        TimeUntilTrigger = cal.getTimeInMillis();

                    }
```

This is my full test code.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                repetition+=3;
                while (counter<repetition){

                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,55+counter*2);
                    timeDatabase.insertData(result.getContents(),String.valueOf(10),String.valueOf(55+counter*2));
                    long TimeUntilTrigger;
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > cal.getTimeInMillis()){
                        TimeUntilTrigger = cal.getTimeInMillis() + 86400000;

                    }else{
                        TimeUntilTrigger = cal.getTimeInMillis();

                    }

                    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),counter,alarmIntent,0);


                    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,TimeUntilTrigger,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

                    counter++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The problem was that you need to set your Seconds and milliseconds.

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,51+counter*2);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```